# Unable to parse JSON from StreamTransformer on unending stream

Tags: json, dart, stream

New to Dart. It seems that `.transform(JsonDecoder())` will hang until the stream is closed or throw an error if it starts to see a new Json object. I could cache the entire strings and parse them that way, but I would like to take advantage of the stream an not store more than is needed in memory.

Is there a way to get the JsonDecoder to push an object to the sink as soon as it gets a complete valid Json Object? I've tried extending some of the internal classes, but only got a private library error.

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/1278bd5adb6a857580f137e47bc521976222f7b9/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/convert_patch.dart#L1500 . This seems to be the relevant code and it's really a pain in my butt. Would I need to create a dummy stream or something?

Comment: How does your JSON object look like? If it is just one big JSON Array, Dart's default JSON parser will need to have the full object before it can return it. There might be some package on pub.dev which can parse more lazily but I don't know. An easy optimization you can do if you are in control of the JSON, is to have a JSON object per line since that makes it easier to process as a stream of JSON objects.

Comment: It's newline terminated JSON rpc2, its just that sometimes the responses are large enough to not fit in one chunk, otherwise I would just use `.map(jsonDecode)`. I think I'll need to write my own Json decoder to deal with this which sucks because everything is already in the sdk...

Maybe I can update https://github.com/llamadonica/dart-json-stream-parser which seems to do what I want...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input is newline separated, you can do:

```dart
Stream jsonObjects = inputStream
    .transform(utf8.decoder)  // if incoming is bytes.
    .transform(const LineSplitter())
    .map(jsonDecode);
```

The `JsonDecoder` converter only works on a single JSON value, because the JSON grammar doesn't allow more than one value in a JSON source text.

The `LineSplitter` will buffer until it has an entire line, then emit one line at a time, so if each JSON message is on a line by itself, that makes each event from the line-splitted stream a complete JSON value.

Comment: The issue with this is that the json may or may not be entirely in the chunk so I cannot just map to decode. I guess I'll just bite the bullet and cache the entire string.

Comment: The `LineSplitter` ensures that the resulting string contains one string per incoming *line*, even if that line is split into multiple chunks. It buffers until it has an entire line, then emits one line at a time. Try it, it will work!